# getting rack mapped directory inside app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger, rack

Say I have a config.ru like:

```
map '/foo' do
  run MyApp
end
```

and a Sinatra app like:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  use Rack::Session::File, key: 'rack.session', domain: 'my.domain.com', path: '/foo', expire_after: 86400 * 14, secret: 'mysecret'
end
```

How can I make MyApp agnostic to which request directory (`/foo` in this case) is used to access it? I have found that `request.script_name` contains this directory, but I cannot use it for the `path:` parameter of the `use Rack::Session::File` statement since it is not defined yet when starting the app from passenger, but only when requests are sent to the application later.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's impossible even with dirty hacks.

So I suppose it's possible to do via two different ways:

1. External configuration file e.g. routes.yml (config.ru uses it for
   `map` statement, application to discover such prefix in url);
2. Environment variable (I've chosen this because it's easy to configure on Heroku.